# Mysql regex search with digit

Tags: mysql, regex

How would I do the following in mysql?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE search REGEXP '.+season\d+\s?.+' limit 10;
```

I want to match something like:

```
"hello this is season1 how are you?"
```

But not:

```
"hello this is season1episode1 how are you?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression since `\d` and `\s` are not available on MySQL. You can use [character classes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead.

You can replace `\d` with `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` and `\s` with `[[= =]]` or `[ ]`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE search REGEXP '.+season[[:digit:]]+[[= =]].+' LIMIT 10

-- or...
SELECT * FROM table WHERE search REGEXP '.+season[0-9]+[ ].+' LIMIT 10
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68cc456b8064674f4aee54b6b90719f8)

Comment: Thanks -- what's the `[= =]` mean?

Comment: @David542 - `[= =]` matches space character

Comment: thanks for this great answer. I've never seen the `[= =]` before, just `\s` or ` `. Where does `[= =]` come from?

Comment: I think you are missing a pair of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Before MySQL 8.0,

```
REGEXP "season[0-9]+[[:>:]]"
```

meaning "season", at least one digit, then a word boundary.  Note that it will stop with punctuation.

```
REGEXP "season[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z]"
```

Might work for you -- it says that it should be followed by a letter.

8.0 changes the word boundary to:

```
REGEXP "season[0-9]+\b"
```

(Caveat:  the backslash may need to be doubled up.)